# Git show whole file changes

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, git-show

Is there a way to get the `git show` command to show the whole contents of a file when viewing a commit? For example: if it currently show something like

```
foo.cpp

+++ int main() {
+++    std::cout << "HELLO" << std::endl;
+++ }
```

I would want the output to say:

```
foo.cpp

#include <stdio> //assuming this was from an earlier commit

+++ int main() {
+++    std::cout << "HELLO" << std::endl;
+++ }
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is kind of a hack, but `git show` (like `git diff`) has the `-U` option that lets you specify how many lines of context to show. If you use a number that's bigger than the region between the difference and the start or end of the file, then it'll show the whole file. So if you use a really big number, it'll work the way you want on (hopefully) any file you try it on:

```
git show -U99999
```

Answer (score 2):

This command show whole file:

```
git show HEAD:./<path_to_file>
```

And it works also for any revision:

```
git show <rev-id>:./<path_to_file>
```