# For "git diff" is there a -U<infinity> option to show the whole file?

Tags: git

I need to generate a full-context git diff programmatically for a web ui.

A CLI for generating a full-context diff was covered in questions:

- [How to get git diff with full context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627598/how-to-get-git-diff-with-full-context)
- [Git show whole file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238258/git-show-whole-file-changes)

The prevalent answer is something like `git diff -U99999`

With a `-U / --unified` option with a ridiculously high threshold (e.g. 999,999), doing `git diff -U999999`:

1. Makes me suspect that there could be a performance hit
2. Even worse, it's a correctness issue if my file is larger than 1M lines

Is there a -U option to show the whole file?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27857967/2541573

Comment: Another option is `git diff -U\`wc -l <file> |cut -f 1 -d" "\` HEAD^  <file>` but you need to run `wc` on the longer version of the file

Comment: `-W` is very useful, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get git diff with full context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627598/how-to-get-git-diff-with-full-context)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just use a large number with `-U`, you could choose the large number to be the point at which *your application* can't handle displaying such a large file (diff).

> it's a correctness issue if my file is larger than 1M lines

And to address this issue, you can check the output for more than one `@@ ... @@` line to determine whether it's complete — this allows you to avoid silently giving a wrong number.

Comment: Experimentally, I found `git diff -U999999999999999999` gave `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.  However, one digit less, `-U99999999999999999`, worked.  Also, adding two or more digits to the first command, `-U999999999999999999999999`, caused it to behave as though the option had actually been `-U0`.

Comment: "-U 999999999" for current OS X (more 9s will fail)

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, the best option is to use `git difftool` rather than vanilla `git diff`. To see which tools your version of git supports, enter

```
git difftool --tool-help
```

which, with my version (2.3.0), shows the following

```
$ git difftool --tool-help
'git difftool --tool=<tool>' may be set to one of the following:
        araxis
        gvimdiff
        gvimdiff2
        gvimdiff3
        meld
        vimdiff
        vimdiff2
        vimdiff3

The following tools are valid, but not currently available:
        bc
        bc3
        codecompare
        deltawalker
        diffmerge
        diffuse
        ecmerge
        emerge
        kdiff3
        kompare
        opendiff
        p4merge
        tkdiff
        xxdiff
```

I usually use `meld`, but that's just a personal preference. `git difftool` takes the same arguments as `git diff` plus a few to help with the process (I find `-y` useful to prevent the prompts when moving from one file to the next).

To check out the changes introduced by a specific commit, for example, you can use

```
git difftool -y -t meld 08f0f82^..08f0f82
```

obviously replacing `08f0f82` with the correct SHA-1.

My biggest complaint is that it launches the tool for each modified file in sequence (hence specifying the `-y` option).

If you only wanted to examine the changes to a particular file in that commit, you can just add the filename to the command line.

```
git difftool -y -t meld 08f0f82^..08f0f82 myfile.c
```

Obviously, this is for interactive use - not for scripting

Comment: I need this for accessing programmatically from a web ui. Sorry did not make it clear right away.

Comment: This answer doesn't even address the question of getting a full-context diff without lines removed.